# How to use LINQ in DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, lambda

I'm trying to use `LINQ` in `DataTable` and I use Ntier for my solution, But when I'm try to use `LINQ` in `DataTable` it gives me an error: Sorry for my english

```
Error   1   Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type c:\users\ba-ojt\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\GoActiveDirectory\PresentationTier\Default.aspx.cs    21  25  PresentationTier
```

How can I fix this
and how it become a lambda expression?

MyCode:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataServiceReference.Service1Client newService = new DataServiceReference.Service1Client();
        DataTable dt = newService.GetAccounts();

        var query = from data in dt
                    select data;//Error Here

        Repeater1.DataSource = query;
        Repeater1.DataBind();

    }
```

MyReference:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `AsEnumerable()` like this:

```
var query = from data in dt.AsEnumerable()
            select data;
```

Update:
Then to get the columns from the datatable you can do this:

```
data.Field<YourType>("YourColumnName")
```

Reference:

- [DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var query = (from DataRow data in dt.Rows
            select data).ToList();
```